# for loops for functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

```
f1=@(x) x-2;
f2=@(x) x;
f3=@(x) x+2;

for i=1:3
    if fi(0)<0
        f2(3)
    else
        f3(3)
    end
end
```

The expected answer is 3,5,5 but when I run the code in matlab I am getting  5,5,5

Comment: I think you meant to use `i` in there somewhere. And `fi` is not defined.

Comment: `fi(0)<0` , this condition is false and not dependent on iterations of the loop. ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ `fi(0)` returns `0` and the condition `0<0` is false

Comment: you would probably like to change `if fi(0)<0` with this: `if f1(i)<0`

Comment: @Sardar_Usama what's `fi`??   (I mean, it's not even defined, why would fi(0) return 0? How did you get that?)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou [`fi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/fi.html) is a built-in function!  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: holy crap! I've never seen that before! (I'm on octave and octave doesn't have it, hahah) ... what the hell is it??

Comment: You know, this is what I like about stackoverflow. Out of a silly question (no offence, OP :p ) can come out a procrastination gem like this. Now I'm reading about Fixed-Point Arithmetic in embedded processors! xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you meant

```
>> f1 = @(x) x - 2;
>> f2 = @(x) x;
>> f3 = @(x) x + 2;
```

```
>> for i = 1 : 3
     if f1(i)<0; f2(3), else; f3(3), end;
   end
ans =  3
ans =  5
ans =  5
```

Right?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using loops, perhaps you want to do vector

```
f1=@(x) x-2;
f2=@(x) x;
f3=@(x) x+2;
f=@(x) (f1(x) < 0).*(f2(3)) + (f1(x) >= 0).*(f3(3))
f(1:3)

ans =

     3     5     5
```

Comment: because i cannot upvote your answer i am typing thnx here